# Using just the name of a Freeform recipient in a notification template

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using the recipients="yes" option in my form, and I have a number of recipients specified in the form parameters using the pipe-separated format (eg. recipient1="somename|somevalue@example.com"). Is there a way to include just the part before the pipe ("somename") in a notification template? I can add the custom field {recipient_email} but that places both parts into the template, including the email address. I just want the first bit. Possible?

EDIT:
I'm similarly struggling to find a way to pass the name value of the selected email address to the return (Thank You) page. For example, if the user chooses the second of three email address from the form's select menu and that recipient is specified as recipient2="Joe Smith|jsmith@example.com" then I want to be able to have a line of the form's Return page that says "You sent this information to Joe Smith". So far I haven't found a way, even using Stash to save a variable to the database.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#freeform_recipient_name1) it looks like to get just the email you can use:

```
{freeform:recipient_value1}
```

And to get just the name you can use:

```
{freeform:recipient_name1}
```

Comment: AFAIK the {freeform:xxxxx} tags are just for use in page templates. Eg, the options for my select menu in the form (where the user specifies which recipient the email goes to) are defined using: 
<option value="{freeform:recipient_value}">{freeform:recipient_name}</option> 
But using that tag in the *notification* template — ie. the template used for the outgoing email — simply places the tag in the email text unparsed.

Comment: Basically, I am looking for an equivalent to {freeform:recipient_name} that can be used and parsed correctly in the Notification template.

Comment: Also: Worth noting that my <option> elements are specified using the {freeform:recipients}…{/freeform:recipients} looping tag pair, rather than the individually-numbered recipient tag you referred to. Either way is valid in the form itself. But for the notification I need the email to show the name selected in the form, so specifying an individual recipient number won't work. I tried the same approach that I used in the form, using the following in the notification template:
{freeform:recipients} {if freeform:recipient_selected} {freeform:recipient_name} {/if} {/freeform:recipients}… No luck.

Comment: sorry I missed that this was in the notification... don't have a fix for you.

Comment: There seems no easy way to do this. The recipient tags (eg. {freeform:recipient_name} are, as far as I can see, only permitted in the form itself (because they reference the form tag's parameters). I cobbled together a workaround for the Thank You page by using Switchee to analyse the {freeform:field:recipient_email} variable and spit out some text for each case, but it's rather clunky and brittle. And I can't see how to do it in the notification templates at all. (If nobody has come up with a better solution in a few days then I guess I'll post my workaround as an ‘answer’, of sorts).

Comment: Further oddness: cruft-removing plug-ins such as Trimmer do not seem to touch the output of the {freeform:field:recipient_email} tag at all. I thought to simply excise the email address part of the tag's output by wrapping the tag with a Trimmer tag pair, but the tag's output remained unaltered. Applying the *same* Trimmer tag pair to the plain text of the {freeform:field:recipient_email}  tag's output (ie. applying Trimmer direct to that text, not to the tag itself) did work, so the Trimmer settings were not at fault. Parse order? Something special about Freeform tags? Seems odd.